# Converting Equations Into Bit-shifting Operations

Tags: c, optimization, bit-shift, performance

**Is there any standard way for converting an (any) equation into bit-shift operations?**

By this I mean converting any thing that is not a + or - into bit-shifts, so the end equation contains only the operands **<<, >>, +, and -**. This is in the interest of making formulas less processor intensive.

Obviously these resultant equations will only be approximations, giving better accuracy with the more orders considered (first-order, second-order e.t.c).

I have scoured the web for any information on this but can't find any, except for stuff on specific formulas (sin, cos, inv e.t.c).

I was envisioning something like a polynomial or Taylor's expansion procedure, and then converting that to bit-shift operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you're reducing something to *simpler* instructions, doesn't mean they're going to execute faster or be less intensive in some way. While you may be able to reduce many things to a reduced subset of operations, you're probably going to need many many more operations to accomplish the same task. A processor can only execute so many operations per second, and you're going to run into that first.

Generally when trying to optimize something at a low level, you're trying to make use of the far more complex opcodes so that you need fewer of them. As an example, you can perform multiplication by doing many ADD instructions. But, for anything other than the most trivial of examples, it's going to take substantially more ADDs than the single MUL opcode that it took, and take far longer to execute.

Getting back to your actual question though... Totally ignoring efficiency, you can calculate anything as long as the instruction set you have is *Turing Complete*. You actually can calculate anything using [a single instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer), if you're careful how you choose that instruction. I don't believe there's any general purpose way of saying "Convert any arbitrary algorithm into using only these instructions", that's generally the job of a compiler writer.

Comment: `that's generally the job of a compiler writer` ... or a job for `genetic programming` task :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not in general.

On most CPUs, multiplication is not significantly slower than other arithmetic operations, so there is little purpose in trying to convert multiplication to bit shifting operations, other than multiplication by constant powers of two.

As far as division goes, there are some well-known methods for converting division by a constant to multiplication by the inverse, and these methods are quite productive. See http://www.flounder.com/multiplicative_inverse.htm for an explanation of how. Division by non-constant values cannot really be optimized, though.

Raising 2 to a power (or dividing a number by a power of 2) is, of course, easily converted to bit shifting. Other exponentiations are not easily converted, though.

Most transcendental functions cannot be sensibly represented on a bitwise level. It doesn't help that most are not defined on integers anyway.

Comment: Interesting about the division, this part was the most time consuming section of the code I was running on an embedded Cortex-M3. Changing to inversed-multiplication really sped things up.

Answer (score 1):

Software multiplication with bit-wise operations is not likely to beat hardware multiplication on modern CPUs.

Usually going down to bit-wise manipulation can yield better performances if it allows to avoid 1) loops; and 2) branching.

[A good online cookbook](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for bit hacking. Otherwise there is [A Hacker's delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654).